# Hacer que AJAX NO me dé una respuesta, sino que me redireccione a la página

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Ya he conseguido la validación del login en mi página web, pero a la hora de reenviarlo a su página de usuario NO consigo hacerlo (NO redirecciona), sino que obtengo como respuesta la página de usuario.

Este es el código AJAX:

```
$('#form-inicio-sesion').trigger('reset');
$('#form-inicio-sesion').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    data: {
      usuariois: $('#usuarioIS').val(),
      contrasenais: $('#contrasenaIS').val()
    },
    url: './Controllers/UserController.php?action=ajax-session',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log("RESPUESTA -> ", response);
    },

    error: function(error) {
      console.log("ERROR ->", error); // Imprimir respuesta de error
    }
  });
});
```

Cuando se envía la información va a este PHP, que verifica que los valores NO estén vacíos y haga la consulta a la base de datos para luego redirigirlo.

```php
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'ajax-session' && !empty($_POST['usuariois']) && !empty($_POST['contrasenais'])){
    $usercontroler = new UserController();
    $usercontroler->VerificaInicio($_POST['usuariois'],$_POST['contrasenais']);
    $usercontroler->VistaUsuario(); // esta es la redireccion.
    // return;
}
```

También dejo código de la función que redirige:

```
public function VistaUsuario()
{   
    include '../Views/User/Index-user.php';
}
```

Comment: ¿Y si en lugar de recibir la vista coges y haces un location.assign() de la misma en el **success** página recargandola?  Es decir, que el ajax simplemente te verifique que el inicio de sesión ha sido correcto y en la linea siguiente le pones el location

Comment: ¿Sería vulnerable a SQL Inyección de esa manera? Nos presionan mucho con eso

Comment: El cambio seria en el ajax, no en el PHP, que es el que hace las consultas a la base de datos en este caso, por lo tanto la inyección SQL no tiene nada que ver con este cambio que sugiero.  En todo caso, la consulta la debe hacer el método `VerificaInicio()` pero como no has puesto lo que hace ni como lo hace no te puedo decir si está bien o no. De todos modos, eso seria una nueva pregunta, no mezclemos temas porque entonces nadie entiende nada cuando visita esta pregunta.

Comment: success: function(data) {
 if (data) {
  document.location.href = data;
 }
}

Comment: Ya lo hice, y si me funciono. Muchísimas gracias